# Excel Enquiry. How do I get this

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

How do I make *Pic 1* look like *Pic 2*?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqDBR.png]

Answer (score 1):

You need to select `abc` and `def` cells, unmerge them using this button:

[image: button].